# Sending images to a whatsapp number with Twilio

Tags: go, twilio, twilio-api

Using https://github.com/twilio/twilio-go I am trying to send multiple images (4 images) to a users phone number.

How can I do this? I went through the docs and attempted to create the solutions using the docs provided by Twilio but was unable to do it correctly.

Could anyone help please.

Thank you

tried using the mediaURL

Comment: Can you please share the code you tried to ran and explain what prevented you from being successful (error log or so)?

Answer (score 0):

```golang
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/go/install
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/twilio/twilio-go"
    api "github.com/twilio/twilio-go/rest/api/v2010"
)

func main() {
    // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
    client := twilio.NewRestClient()

    params := &api.CreateMessageParams{}
    params.SetBody("This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?")
    params.SetFrom("+15017122661")
    params.SetMediaUrl([]string{"https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg"})
    params.SetTo("+15558675310")

    resp, err := client.Api.CreateMessage(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        if resp.Sid != nil {
            fmt.Println(*resp.Sid)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(resp.Sid)
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more languages in the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/go#code-send-an-mms-with-an-image-url).